# Are there any good Equinox P2 core api examples?

Tags: eclipse, equinox, p2

Everything I can find on the web just shows really easy high level tutorials like how to use the P2 ui in your RCP application or how to use the operations api.

I can't really find any good information how how to make a custom P2 installation process. The information is scattered everywhere and all the advanced tutorials I could find were for Helios, which had that provisional api, which is different from the Indigo P2 api.

As an idea for what I want to do, my RCP app connects to a remote PC that runs some embedded hardware and communicates a bunch of random hardware status info.  That remote pc has some C code on it and we regularly update the binaries for it, which changes the way the RCP app has to communicate with it.

What I'd like to do is have the binary in an IU that other packages can depend on. Then when P2 installs that new IU, I can then run another class that will remotely install the binary on the other computer.